# what is required to get an 05 subaru impreza ej20 engine running in another car

Tags: subaru, impreza, engine-swap

i have picked up a subaru ej22 out of an 05 impreza. it came with the ecu, central locking unit, ignition barrel/switch, key security module and door locks.

i am heading to a wreckers next week to pull the engine to ecu harness and try and pull the dash harness (if i cant get it out i will cut off the connectors i need with a tail.).

i will have to slim down the dash harness alot so as not to make a mess.

is there anything else i will need to get? i am going to be putting it in a 96 impreza. im guessing ill also need the obd2 harness if it is not part of the dash harness.

i have the wireing diagrams for both cars but they dont state what is required, just everything.

UPDATE

looks like the person i bought the engine off was either miss informed or lied. the engine is not from a 2005 impreza. as best i can tell it is a phase2 engine from a 99-01 outback?

knowing what liitle info i have about this engine, what will i need for a swap into a car that currently has a 96 ej18. the ecu and security stuff seems to be from an 05 impreza so i really dont know whats happend.

UPDATE 2

ok, found out what has happend. the car the engine came from was an 05 imprezza, with an ej20. at some point they must have done a bottom end as the heads were removed and the ej20 block was replaced with an ej22. the ej20 heads and all accesories where bolted back up. so it is now a higher compression ej22.

so the question now is. is there anything else i will need from an 05 imprezza to get this engine running? its a dual port exhast engine and i have dual port headers so thats fine. i am still going to the wreckers to get the engine to ecu loom and am going to try and pull the whole dash loom. i will be keeping the pre obd2 instrument cluster. i will have to strip the dash loom down to bare minimum, luckely there is pretty much nothing in the 96 imprezza that it is going into that is ecu controlled (except the engine of course.) so for the most part i wont have to touch it.

Comment: I don’t think the wiring diagrams were created to aid swapping motors ...

Comment: You will most likely need the full harness engine / ecu / obd2 and the relevant sensors - it may also mean either having the door switches or being able to by-pass them.

Comment: the wiring diagram was more to sort out the wiring. as for door switch's i dont think the would prevent the engine starting as i have an 06 liberty (legacy) and can start the car with door open. the engine is complete with all bolt on's and sensors. only thing it does not have is the exhaust. i will probably have to weld in another bung in my exhast, post cat for a second o2 sensor. i wont be using the dash or anything from the 2005. just the engine, ecu and anything needed to start the engine. so basicly all the security stuff.

Comment: Best advice : get all that you can... and don't throw any of it away until it's done... Was the donor auto or manual?

Comment: manual and so is mine. but the car i'm getting the harness from is not the same car as the one i got the engine from (unsure if its manual or auto). i dont have the budget to get "everything"

Comment: I don't think what you have is an EJ22. To my knowledge, the 05 Impreza came with either an EJ20 or EJ25. I'm in the process of putting an EG33 into a 96 Impreza right now ... which is a lot of work. I'd bet if you have the wiring harness out of the newer car, you'd be able to fit everything right in. Considering you are staying OBDII for the new engine and staying as a 4 cyl, the dash should work right. The part you are probably going to have issues with is the exhaust.

Comment: it is definatly an ej22. i am in australia and quite often we get diffrent combinations than elsewhere. the 96 it is going into also is NOT an obd2 car.  obd2 is not required in aus untill around 2005-6 so manufactueres used up all the old ecu's here. looking at the wiring diagram of the 96 looks like the only things in the guage's that is controlled by the ecu is the tach and the engine light. both of which should be easy to wire up.

Comment: is the exhaust manifold different from 96 to 05? the car currently has an ej18 in it. i do have a 96 liberty (legacy) with an ej22 in it that i could steel the exhaust off if need be (its no longer on the road)

Comment: The EG22 could come with 2 port exhaust per side or single port exhaust. That is what would give you the trouble. If you have the exhaust manifolds already, there shouldn't be an issue there.

Comment: i do not have the exhaust manifolds for the ej22. is there an easy way of telling just by looking at the block?

Comment: ok. thats sorted. found out the diffrence. if anyone else is looking. if it has the standerd 2 holes near each other it is a duel port engine. if it only has a single hole on each head its a single port. my headers will fit fine as both engines are dual port. looks like the heads are from either an ej20 or ej25 but the block is from an ej22. previous owner must have done a bottom end. any one know how to tell what the heads are from?

Comment: Years ago i had 96 twin turbo legacy with an EJ20. I wanted to convert it to singe turbo. I found the wiring looms were quite different but more importantly sensors had different voltages and operated in different directions. 0-5v vs 3-0v etc. (I decided to cancel the project) If the loom engine and ecu match hopefully you should be ok. Good luck.