# Which engines will fit my 1999 Legacy Outback

Tags: engine, subaru, outback, legacy

I just started hearing some ticking in my engine.  It seems to be coming from the main block, so I'm thinking it's probably a rod bearing.  I've been doing a bit of browsing on Craigslist and eBay for JDM engines, but I'm confused as to which engines will actually work should I decide to go that route (replacing the engine).

I have a 1999 Subaru Legacy Outback Limited.  I already switched out the engine from a 98 that I crashed, but I don't know what other options I have. DOHC EJ25 currently.  I'm looking for a plug-and-play transfer (hopefully little or no wiring).

- Will model years other than '99/'98 work?  If so, which ones?
- Will SOHC EJ25s work? (Do they make those?)
- Will EJ20s work?  Pros/Cons?
- I read something about 2.2L engines working(?)  Was I seeing things?

Comment: From what I see, I believe your engine is the EJ25D, which was the dog of the Subaru line. Mating one Subaru engine in place of another is usually not an issue, it's getting it to work right which is. The EJ22 engine should fit, but again, would need lots of work to get it running. I'm sure you've seen what I was just reading, but most would suggest you throw your car away and get a different one. Especially if it has high mileage (200K+ kinda range). It just isn't worth it. This is strictly opinion, so take it for what it's worth.

Comment: Little or no wiring means using the same engine generally. A different engine may need a different transmission, diff, all sorts of things.

Comment: @GdD Thanks.  What I'm wondering is what that means for my case.  For example, I can use either a '98 or '99 engine (I know because I tried it :)), but I don't know if a '97 or '99 would work.

Comment: There were three different iterations of the EJ25D, though I think the internals made most of the differences. I got a lot of information [from this forum post](https://sl-i.net/FORUM/archive/index.php/t-16437.html). It may be of use to you.

Comment: You may find this post interesting / useful : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/52396/10976